# How do I pass one or more arguments to python, match them against an optional filter argument, and add only matching arguments to an array?

Tags: python, dependencies, arguments, argparse, optional-parameters

I want to:

1. pass *one or more (*)* `named` arguments to a python script,
2. pass an optional `filter` argument also to the script,
3. match all other `arguments` against the `filter` *(if supplied)*,
4. add all `arguments` *(matching the `filter` argument if supplied)* to an `array[]`,
5. quit with an `error message and syntax help` if no `arguments` are given or if only a `filter` argument is given (the `filter` is dependent upon - requires - other `arguments`).

For example:

```py
python script.py
```

should generate the `usage` help message then quit.

```py
python script.py --arg string
```

should add the arg `string` to the `array[]`.

```py
python script.py --arg string1 --arg string2 --arg string3
```

should add all `arguments` to the `array[]`.

```py
python script.py --arg string1 --arg string2 --arg string3 --filter '*2*'
```

should add *only those `arguments` that match the `filter`* to the `array[]`, so in this case it would only add `string2` to the `array[]` and ignore the rest.

So:

1. there **MUST** be *at **least** one `argument`*,
2. there **MUST** be *at **most** one `filter` argument*,

Here is an example, but it does not work as expected because I don't think `group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)` operates in the way I have explained above - it just requires either argument but does not specify which one is required:

```py
import argparse

# Create an ArgumentParser object
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dependent argument testing')

# Create a mutually exclusive group for the --arg and --filter options
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

# Define the --arg argument (required)
group.add_argument('--arg', type=str, help='Specify the argument')

# Define the --filter argument (optional)
group.add_argument('--filter', type=str, help='Specify the filter (optional)')

# Parse the command-line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Access the values of the arguments
if args.arg:
    print(f'Argument: {args.arg}')
if args.filter:
    print(f'Filter: {args.filter}')
```

Comment: What's wrong with just collecting all the args that were specified and the filter value that was specified (if any), and then using ordinary program logic with the resulting `args` object to filter `args.arg` after the fact? (Also: we call them *lists* in Python, not "arrays". Unless you're using Numpy, the standard library `array` module, or some other such thing to manipulate data in a more low-level way.)

Answer (score 0):

Forget the mutually exclusive group.

To get

```
script.py --arg string1 --arg string2 --arg string3 --filter '*2*'
```

Use '-h/--help' to get automatic usage and help.  Trying to get usage when not given any arguments is possible, but I don't think it's worth the extra effort.

Define '--arg' as an 'append', and you can string as many as you want.

'--filter' can be a default 'store'.

Include a `print(args)` to test.

The rest is post parsing logic and code.

### edit

I'd expect a `args` namespace like

```
Namespace('arg'=['arg1','arg2','arg3'], 'filter'='*2*')
```

Use

```
if args.filter is None:
    ...
```

to test if filter was provided or not

```
if args.arg is empty:
     .....
```

to test is that was provided or not.

Iterate on `args.arg` to apply the `filter` and build a new list.  A for loop or list comprehension should work.

The `arg` argument could also be a `nargs='+'` instead of `action='append'`.

If both `args` attributes are empty, you could call  `parse.print_usage()` and exit.